# remote desktop control of raspbian "hdmi" desktop

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

I have a raspberry pi connected to a television screen, via HDMI, and a wired network.

I want to connect to, see and remotely control the raspberry pi HDMI desktop from my remote PC.

Is this possible and if so how might it be achieved?

I've tried using tightVNC but this brings me to a different desktop environment and I cannot "see" mouse movements affecting the HDMI desktop on the television screen.

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out finally.

Just installed realVNC on PC and RPi and voila!!! VNC client on PC controls the RPoi connected HDMI screen output seen on the TV monitor.